# Simple Point of Sale Order Info: How to compile all the Items that a user will input?

Tags: java

I was doing a simple point of sale system, and I'm having a difficulty on outputting all the items that the user will input. So basically it's like a receipt.

Here's the whole code:

```
public class POS {
    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static String again;
    public static String choose;
    public static String description;
    public static String price;
    public static int quantity;
    public static double total ;
    
    public static void menu() {
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t +===========================================+");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t              PCG Computer Shop             ");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t                               ");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t   Code         Description         Unit Price");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t   A001            CPU              Php 6,500");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t   A002        Mother Board         Php 4,500");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t   A003            GPU              Php 25,000");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t   A004            RAM              Php 4,000");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t   A005        Power Supply         Php 5,000");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t   A006           Mouse             Php 500");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t   A007          Monitor            Php 3,000");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t   A008          Keyboard           Php 1,500 ");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t   A009          Headset            Php 600");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t   A010         Microphone          Php 350");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t  +===========================================+");
    }
    
    public static void order() {
        System.out.print("\nSelect Product Code: ");
        choose = input.next();
        
        
        
        //condition
        if(choose.equals("A001")) {
            description = "CPU";
            price = "Php 6,500";
            System.out.print("Enter Quantity: ");
            
            quantity = input.nextInt();
            total = total + (quantity * 6500);
            
            System.out.print("Add Item (y/n)? ");
            again = input.next();
            
            if(again.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                order();        
            }
                        
        }
        else if(choose.equals("A002")) {
            description = "Mother Board";
            price = "Php 4,500";
            System.out.print("Enter Quantity: ");
            quantity = input.nextInt();
            total = total + (quantity * 4500);
            
            System.out.print("Add Item (y/n)? ");
            again = input.next();
            
            if(again.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                order();        
            }
        
            
        }
        
        else if(choose.equals("A003")) {
            description = "GPU";
            price = "Php 25,000";
            System.out.print("Enter Quantity: ");
            quantity = input.nextInt();
            total = total + (quantity * 25000);
            
            System.out.print("Add Item (y/n)? ");
            again = input.next();
            
            if(again.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                order();        
            }
            
            
        }
        else if(choose.equals("A004")) {
            description = "RAM";
            price = "Php 4,000";
            System.out.print("Enter Quantity: ");
            quantity = input.nextInt();
            total = total + (quantity * 4000);
            
            System.out.print("Add Item (y/n)? ");
            again = input.next();
            
            if(again.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                order();        
            }
            
            
        }
        
        else if(choose.equals("A005")) {
            description = "Power Supply";
            price = "Php 5,000";
            System.out.print("Enter Quantity: ");
            quantity = input.nextInt();
            total = total + (quantity * 5000);
            
            System.out.print("Add Item (y/n)? ");
            again = input.next();
            
            if(again.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                order();        
            }
            
            
        }
        else if(choose.equals("A006")) {
            description = "Mouse";
            price = "Php 500";
            System.out.print("Enter Quantity: ");
            quantity = input.nextInt();
            total = total + (quantity * 500);
            
            System.out.print("Add Item (y/n)? ");
            again = input.next();
            
            if(again.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                order();        
            }
            
            
        }
        else if(choose.equals("A007")) {
            description = "Monitor";
            price = "Php 3,000";
            System.out.print("Enter Quantity: ");
            quantity = input.nextInt();
            total = total + (quantity * 3000);
            
            System.out.print("Add Item (y/n)? ");
            again = input.next();
            
            if(again.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                order();        
            }
            
            }
            
        
        
        else if(choose.equals("A008")) {
            System.out.print("Enter Quantity: ");
            description = "Keyboard";
            price = "Php 1,500";
            quantity = input.nextInt();
            total = total + (quantity * 1500);
            
            System.out.print("Add Item (y/n)? ");
            again = input.next();
            
            if(again.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                order();        
            }
            
            }
            
        
        else if(choose.equals("A009")) {
            description = "Headset";
            price = "Php 600";
            System.out.print("Enter Quantity: ");
            quantity = input.nextInt();
            total = total + (quantity * 600);
            
            System.out.print("Add Item (y/n)? ");
            again = input.next();
            
            if(again.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                order();        
            }
            
    
        }
            
        
        else if(choose.equals("A010")) {
            description = "Microphone";
            price = "Php 350";
            System.out.print("Enter Quantity: ");
            quantity = input.nextInt();
            total = total + (quantity * 350);
            
            System.out.print("Add Item (y/n)? ");
            again = input.next();
            
            if(again.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                order();
            
            }
        
    
        }
    

        }
    
    
        //This is supposedly the receipt
    public static void orderInfo() {
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t +======================================================================================+");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t                                   PCG Computer Shop                                  ");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t                                                                   ");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t                                   ORDER INFORMATION                                 ");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t         Code         Description          Unit Price        Quantity       Amount"); 
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t         "   +   choose + "             " + description + "               " + price + "           " + quantity + "           " + total);
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t ");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t"); 
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t +======================================================================================+");


    }
    
        
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        menu();
        order();
        orderInfo();


   }

}
```

I tried setter and getter but it didn't work for me. So I gave up.

This is  what suppose the output should look like

```
 +===========================================+
                              PCG Computer Shop             
                                               
                
                   Code         Description         Unit Price
                
                   A001            CPU              Php 6,500
                   A002        Mother Board         Php 4,500
                   A003            GPU              Php 25,000
                   A004            RAM              Php 4,000
                   A005        Power Supply         Php 5,000
                   A006           Mouse             Php 500
                   A007          Monitor            Php 3,000
                   A008          Keyboard           Php 1,500 
                   A009          Headset            Php 600
                   A010         Microphone          Php 350
                  +===========================================+

Select Product Code: A001
Enter Quantity: 2
Add Item (y/n)? y

Select Product Code: A002
Enter Quantity: 2
Add Item (y/n)? y

Select Product Code: A004
Enter Quantity: 2
Add Item (y/n)? n
                 +======================================================================================+
                                                   PCG Computer Shop                                  
                                                                                   
                
                                                   ORDER INFORMATION                                 
                
                         Code         Description          Unit Price        Quantity       Amount
                         A001             CPU              Php 6,500           2           13000.0
                         A002         Mother Board         Php 4,500           2           9000.0
                         A004             RAM              Php 4,000           2           4000.0
                
                
                
                
                 +======================================================================================+
```

And this is the output that I got:

```
+======================================================================================+
                                                   PCG Computer Shop                                  
                                                                                   
                
                                                   ORDER INFORMATION                                 
                
                         Code         Description          Unit Price        Quantity       Amount
                         A004             RAM               Php 4,000           2           30000.0
                 
                
                
                
                
                 +======================================================================================+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `order` method only allows for the input of exactly one item and you don't have any loop to call it multiple times. Also you do not collect multiple ordered items in an array or list, so you cannot first collect all ordered items and then print them in a summary. Also your output in `orderInfo` does not have a loop and can only output the last ordered item.

What you do right now is a recursive call or the `order` method to itself - this will only work for a certain amount of items, then your call stack will be exhausted. (Probably you will never face that error when you try it, since the stack is not small, and you do not use a lot of it in your program.)

You should create a class (e.g. `OrderedItem`) for an ordered item that stores data like product code, description, price and quantity. Then in a loop let the user enter the ordered items and create a new object of that class per ordered item. Add that object to a list.

In your `orderInfo` method you pass the list of ordered items as parameter and then print the header first, then a loop to print all the individual items from the list, and then you print the footer.